# Output Sanitation

Tags: validation, sanitization

I've read the WP codex and several tutorials about data validation and sanitation in WordPress. Now I've got this simple example code:

`$title = "<script>alert('Test')</script>";
echo esc_html($title);`

According to the tutorials and the codex this should be the output:
`&lt;script&gt;alert&#40;&#39;test&#39;&#41;&lt;&#47;script&gt;`

But on my website I get this:
`<script>alert('Test')</script>`.

Am I doing something wrong? Because the XSS isn't being executed, so the esc_html filter is working correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working correctly. If you look at the source code of the page, you will see:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(&#039;Test&#039;)&lt;/script&gt;
```

When the above text gets processed for display by your browser, it then becomes

```
<script>alert('Test')</script>
```

which is what you want to be **displayed**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You're correct, in the source it looks correct. Thanks!